# Issues remapping and combining two speakers in pulseaudio

Tags: bash, shell-script, ubuntu, pulseaudio

I have a pair of Bluetooth speakers and a pair of line-in speakers that I am trying to play simultaneously. I have no trouble connecting and playing off of either, but connecting them has presented many problems. Additionally, my bluetooth speakers are setup flipped, so I am remapping them to match the correct positioning.

I saw several threads on that described how to flip speakers using pulseaudio's `module-remap-sink`, and combine speakers using `module-combine-sink`. I also wanted to add a latency to the hardline speakers to account for a bluetooth delay, so I included a `module-null-sink` and looped its monitor source into the hardline sink to get this delay. My four commands are listed below.

**NOTE: I split long lines here with backslashes for formatting purposes. Each command is one line in the actual code**

```
pacmd load-module module-null-sink sink_name=delayed_speakers \
    sink_properties=device.description=DelayedSpeakers
pacmd load-module module-remap-sink sink_name=remapped_bluetooth \ 
    master=bluez_sink.EC_81_93_5A_66_BB.a2dp_sink channels=2 \
    master_channel_map=front-left,front-right channel_map=rear-right,rear-left remix=no 
pacmd load-module module-loopback latency_msec=80 source=delayed_speakers.monitor \
    sink=alsa_output.usb-Generic_USB_Audio-00.analog-stereo
pacmd load-module module-combine-sink slaves=remapped_bluetooth,delayed_speakers \ 
    sink_name=CombinedSink sink_properties=device.description=CombinedSpeakers \
    channel_map=front-left,front-right,rear-left,rear-right
```

This sequence of commands works fine when I run each command one by one from a bash terminal, but I want to setup this to run on boot, so I wrote a bash script that contains these lines. When I run the bash script, the combinedSpeakers sink never loads. To investigate this, I commented out the line and tested each `delayed_speakers` and `remapped_bluetooth` individually. If I put module-remap-sink before module-loopback, then the hardline audio receives the output from both the `delayed_speakers` and the `remapped_bluetooth` (including proper remapping) outputs. If I flip the order of these lines, the bluetooth speaker receives the output of both lines. I have tried adding a sleep for 10 seconds between each module-loading, but this does not resolve the issue either. I included my script below.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Loading null sink";
pacmd load-module module-null-sink sink_name=delayed_speakers \
    sink_properties=device.description=DelayedSpeakers

sleep 10
echo "Loading remap sink"
pacmd load-module module-remap-sink sink_name=remapped_bluetooth \
    master=bluez_sink.EC_81_93_5A_66_BB.a2dp_sink channels=2 \
    master_channel_map=front-left,front-right channel_map=rear-right,rear-left \
    remix=no

sleep 10
echo "Loading delayed speakers loopback"
pacmd load-module module-loopback latency_msec=80 source=delayed_speakers.monitor \
    sink=alsa_output.usb-Generic_USB_Audio-00.analog-stereo

sleep 10
echo "Loading combined sink"
pacmd load-module module-combine-sink slaves=remapped_bluetooth,delayed_speakers \
    sink_name=CombinedSink sink_properties=device.description=CombinedSpeakers \
    channel_map=front-left,front-right,rear-left,rear-right
```

When I check pulseaudio log from `systemctl --user status pulseaudio`, I see 100 or more messages of
`pulseaudio[7998]: q overrun, queuing locally`,
and a single message of
`No remapping configured, proceeding nonetheless!`.
After this, I can no longer execute any `pactl` or `pacmd` commands until I restart pulseaudio with `sudo pkill -9 pulseaudio`.

EDIT: I know I can add module-loading to the default.pa file, but this isn't working in my case because my bluetooth speaker isn't connected when the file runs, so the module-loading would fail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the issue. It turns out that the failure wasn't with scripting, it was just a coincidence. The failure occured whenever I attempt to use `module-remap-sink` on a sink that is the default-sink. This failure occurs silently and pacmd exists as normal. It is only when I attempt to `set-default` to this new remapped sink or create a combined-sink including it that pulseaudio becomes unresponsive.

Solution: Use `pacmd set-default-sink 0` before using `module-remap-sink` (or another index if the problematic sink is sink 0). If the problematic sink is the only sink, then you can create a dummy sink using `pacmd load-module module-null-sink`, switch to it, configure your remapping, and finally delete the dummy.

Comment: That was such a weird issue I almost didn't believe the explanation, since my module configuration hasn't changed in a year and suddenly didn't work anymore, but turns out I was indeed running into the exact same problem and creating a dummy sink made it work.

Answer (score 2):

Just for the record, the exact same problem occurs when trying to remap sources instead of sinks.

Doing the same thing for sources worked fine:

```
pactl load-module module-null-source source_name=dummy-temp-source
pactl set-default-source dummy-temp-source
```

Then do all your sources remapping commands. No need to add extra sleep in between !!

And finally switch to one of the sources you've created:

```
pactl set-default-source my-newly-created-source
```

And remove the temporary one

```
pactl unload-module module-null-source
```

Remark: I noticed the module `module-null-source` is not listed in the [pulseaudio modules documentation](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/). I was wondering why but by using command line completion in my shell it was listed in the possible completions... I tried it, and it works as expected...

Can't vote as I do not have enough reputation, but thanks a lot @scott-driggers ! I was really banging my head on the fact something was working in the shell but not in the context of a script, and went through the stupid way of adding extra sleeps...